# How to pass df column as parameter to the function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wrote below function

```scala
object AgeClassification {
  def AgeCategory(age:Int) : String = {
    if(age<=30)
      return "Young" 
    else if(age>=65)
      return "Older" 
    else
      return "Mid-age"
  }
}
```

and I am trying to pass dataframe column as parameter

```scala
val df_new = df
  .withColumn("Age_Category", AgeClassification.AgeCategory(df("age")))
```

but getting the error

> :33: error: type mismatch;
>    found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>    required: Int
>    val df_new = df.withColumn("Age_Category",AgeClassification.AgeCategory(df("age")))

How to pass column as parameter?

```
val df_new = df
  .withColumn("Age_Category",AgeClassification.AgeCategory(df.age.cast(IntegerType)))
```

> :33: error: value age is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>          val df_new = df.withColumn("Age_Category",AgeClassification.AgeCategory(df.age.cast(IntegerType)))

```scala
val df_new = df
   .withColumn("Age_Category", AgeClassification.AgeCategory(df("age").cast(Int)))
```

> :33: error: overloaded method value cast with alternatives:
>     (to: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column 
>     (to: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>    cannot be applied to (Int.type)
>          val df_new = df.withColumn("Age_Category",AgeClassification.AgeCategory(df("age").cast(Int)))

Answer (score 3):

You can not use scala functions directly when manipulating a dataframe with the SparkSQL API. You can only use "column" functions, defined in the [`Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html) class, or in the [`functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) class. They basically tranform columns into columns. The actual computations are handled within Spark.

To illustrate this, you can try this in the REPL:

```scala
scala> df("COL1").cast("int")
res6: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CAST(COL1 AS INT)
```

The type is `Column`, not `int` and this is why scala refuses to apply your function (that epects an integer) on such an object.

To use a custom function, you need to wrap it in a UDF like this:

```scala
val ageUDF = udf((age : Int) => AgeClassification.AgeCategory(age))
// or shorter
val ageUDF = udf(AgeClassification.AgeCategory _)

// The you may use it this way:
df.withColumn("classif", ageUDF(df("age")))
```

Note also that `df.age` works in pyspark but it is not valid ni scala. For a short way to access columns by name, you can import `spark.implicits._` and write `$"age"` or even shorter `'age`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def AgeCategory(age:Column) : String
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.